# Showing special characters in bash echo

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that reads the results of an sql query in which the results are output as HTML (using the -H option) to a file (using the -o option) and then sends those results in an email. When the results are output to the file, they come out as:

```
'<IDLE>'
```

But when I parse them from the output file they show up in the email as:

```
&lt;IDLE&gt;
```

Can anyone help me format these so I get the actual characters and not the entity representation?

**EDIT:** The way I am sending the text now is:

```
echo -e $EMAIL_TXT | mail -s $SUBJECT $RECIPIENT
```

And the way I am extracting the text from the html file ($OUT_FILE) is:

```
QRY_LINE=$(sed "${QRY_LNUM}q;d" $OUT_FILE)
```

Comment: `echo -e`? Why? If you're writing to a file, `mail -s "$subject" "$recipient" <file` makes more sense. If you're not, `mail -s "$subject" "$recipient" <<<"$email_text"` makes more sense. Note the quotes -- they're important if you don't want a `*` in your text to be replaced with a list of filenames in the local directory, or a series of tabs to be replaced with a single space. That said, it's nothing in bash at all that's doing the entity replacement -- I'd take a closer look at your local operating system's mail command.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the mail command, I'm using -e because there are newlines in `$EMAIL_TXT`, the entity replacement is happening when I extract the text from `$OUT_FILE` see my recent edit

Comment: Is `QRY_LINE` supposed to be `$EMAIL_TXT`? Do you see `<IDLE>` when you open your output file in a browser or a text editor?

Comment: @doubleDown: Yes and yes

Comment: Sorry I mean do you see `<IDLE>` in the text editor too, because I was expecting it will be `&lt;IDLE&gt;` there.

Comment: In the html file I do see `<IDLE>`

Comment: You don't need `-e` for the newlines in `$EMAIL_TXT` unless your quoting is wrong -- quote everything properly and you can have literal newlines observed instead of needing to futz with `\n`.

Comment: ...and you absolutely haven't demonstrated that it isn't your mail program. Try creating a file you KNOW contains literal `<` and `>` characters, send them with the `mail` command, and see if the behavior you get is any different.

Comment: Ok I just did that, and it sent the `<` and `>` characters fine... the reason I assumed it wasn't the `mail` command was because when I ran `echo $QRY_LINE` the `>` and `<` characters were already showing up as entities, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the line where I am extracting the text **out of** the html file.

Comment: What does `echo "$QRY_LINE"` alone say? Btw you should edit `QRY_LINE` to `EMAIL_TXT` if they are indeed the same variable.

Comment: Use the `printf` command; its behavior is much more consistent than `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using string replace to replace all `&lt;`s and `&gt;`s with `<` and `>` respectively.